# Is it possible to concatenate rules in Xtext?

Tags: eclipse, grammar, eclipse-emf, xtext, eclipse-emf-ecore

I have a language with a set of keywords in the following form:

```
MyWord1
MyWord2
...
MyWord500
```

Like "MyWord", there are several other keywords with the same range of 500 allowable values. How could I create a grammar to parse this without making a rule with all 500 possible values piped one after the other? After reading the documentation, the closest I've come to a solution is the following:

```
MyWord:
    "MyWord"INT;
```

But Xtext puts a space between MyWord and the integer. Also, INT must be 2 digits for some reason, but I can define my own to get around that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MyWord:
"MyWord"INT;
```

is a datatype rule. to your space problem:
maybe you should use a terminal rule

```
terminal MyWord :
"MyWord" INT;
```

Comment: Thanks! That solved my problem. Is there some useful documentation besides the official? I find it very not useful.